# Encoding and decoding emoji for cross plateforms

Tags: android, emoticons

I am currently working on an android instant messaging application .It is working fine .I am successful in sending messages from one mobile to another,from mobile to web application.i am using library compile 'com.rockerhieu.emojicon:library:1.3.3' to handle emoticons . Using this library , i am adding a panel of emoticons .It is working fine for sending emoticon from one mobile to another .But web application is not getting the emoticon which i am sending .

**ScreenShot**

[image: Enoji]

As u can see in the screen shot a different symbol is displayed in the web application .

**Screen Shot of mobile app**

[image: Mobile App Screen Shot]

Here is the main problem,i am not getting in web app what i am sending through my mobile App.

**ChatActivity.java**

```
     public class ChatActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        EmojiconGridFragment.OnEmojiconClickedListener, EmojiconsFragment.OnEmojiconBackspaceClickedListener {

    EmojiconEditText edMessage = (EmojiconEditText) findViewById(R.id.edtMessage);
 @Override
    public void onEmojiconBackspaceClicked(View view) {
        EmojiconsFragment.backspace(edMessage);
    }

    @Override
    public void onEmojiconClicked(Emojicon emojicon) {
        EmojiconsFragment.input(edMessage, emojicon);
    }

}
```

Please help me to fix the issue.

Comment: You can send unicode of that string and then decode it at both the end

Comment: Anjali , i am using the library compile 'com.rockerhieu.emojicon:library:1.3.3' to handle emoticons . I am using the method and views provided by this library.Now as it is not working for Web application,so should i not use this library.If i dont have to use this library,how can i encode and decode the emoticons.Please give me some references .

Comment: no you can use it. only thing you need to do is find the way to get string form of that emoji and then change to it in unicode after that send to server end

Comment: or try to find the  same lib for server end

Comment: @AnjaliTripathi ,Thanks .Can u suggest me some links that should be followed by me to fix the issue?

Comment: for which solution ?

Comment: i am selecting emoticon through the emoticon panel provided by the library .How to convert it into a form that is stored in the database and is accessible by the web application?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100544/discussion-between-anjali-tripathi-and-deepakr).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `edMessage.getText().toString().trim()` you can get string

Converting **String** to **Unicode**

```
    public static String unicodeEscaped(char ch) {
            if (ch < 0x10) {
                return "\\u000" + Integer.toHexString(ch);
            } else if (ch < 0x100) {
                return "\\u00" + Integer.toHexString(ch);
            } else if (ch < 0x1000) {
                return "\\u0" + Integer.toHexString(ch);
            }
            return "\\u" + Integer.toHexString(ch);
        }

        String unicode = "";
       String text = _msgEditText.getText().toString().trim();
       for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
       unicode = unicode+Constant.unicodeEscaped(text.charAt(i));
                            }
text = unicode;
```

And for decoding it you can use  **common-lang.jar** file.
Please refer link [Click here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6)

```
_msgString = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(_msgString); // for decoding unicode to string or for similar language
```

Comment: Thanks for ur help. I have used  compile 'commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6' for encoding and decoding emoji .

Comment: For Encoding:                                                                                     message = edMessage.getText().toString().trim();
                // Emcoding emoji into unicode characters
                String toServer = StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(message);                                  For Decoding :      //Decoding unicode characters for emoji
                                String messageReceived = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(unicodeMessageReceived);

Comment: if this post helpful for you  pls upvote it and mark it as a right

Comment: I am gettting one issue,When i am sending :-) ,it is displayed as it is . I want to display its corresponding image.How can i execute this task ?

Comment: StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(text) at your end. will decode to respected value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100563/discussion-between-deepakr-and-anjali-tripathi).

Comment: I Got IllegalArgumentException with this library : **Less than 4 hex digits in unicode value: '\u062' due to end of CharSequence**